# Glottal approximate and rhotic consonants and R-colored vowels

Tags: vowels

Is there some reason why the consonant "r" can't simply be a glottal approximate and "er" be the corresponding vowel?

This would explain why different r's can be produced with the tongue in totally different positions yet all sound the same.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_consonant
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel

Comment: You mean pharyngeal? Any voiced (or perhaps any creaky-voiced) vocoid is arguably a "glottal approximant".

Comment: I assumed it was pharyngeal but now I am wondering why it cant simply be glottal.

Comment: @Nardog Breathy-voiced, surely? A glottal approximant should be one where the glottis (presumably = the vocal cords) doesn’t close enough to make actual frication, which would be (very) breathy, or perhaps even just a whisper.

Comment: I now think rhotics are produced by the Vestibular folds.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for not doing so is that it's not clear what sense of "is" you have in mind. Specifically, what do you mean by "r", and at what level of analysis are you asking what *r* "is" (in what language)? I recommend [this paper](https://www.glossa-journal.org/article/id/5145/) by Chabot, "What's wrong with being a rhotic". The main problem is that the letter "r" is used to describe a thing that is phonologically relatively unified, but physically very divergent. [h] is one of the realizations of the rhotic in Brazilian Portuguese (Cristófaro Silva 1998 *Fonética e fonologia do português* p. 51). When a rhotic is pronounced [h], one view of the matter is that you should write [h] and not [r]. I would not hold to that view, but I would say that you should be clear about the phonetics of supposed *r*.